# Cannot interact with page after $state.reload()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add a row in database, after that, reload current page to update new data, but when I use $state.reload(), all page becomes dark and I cannot interact with this page.

```
DeviceService.addDevice($scope.newDevice).then(function (result) {
        if (result.data.success) {
          flash.success = result.data.message;

        // current state is 'profile' and I want to reload to update data
            $state.go('profile', {}, { reload: true });

        } else {
          flash.error = result.data.message;
        }

      });
```

After reload, from this: [image]

becomes this: 
[image]

UPDATE: 
I think maybe it's because I use a modal to add device. Are there anyway to fix it ? How can I close the modal before reload the state. I am using bootstrap modal inside file profile.html

[image]

Comment: Does `profile` state take any params? Also, why don't you just call the get all device API from `DeviceService` rather than reloading the entire page?

Comment: it looks like overlay of the modal, are you using modal for adding new device?

Comment: @Sajal 'profile' does not take any params. Because the get all devices API runs when start state so I want to reload the state to run this again.

Comment: @the_mishra yes, I use a modal to add new device and angular-flash to flash the message (https://github.com/wmluke/angular-flash). Any way to fix it ?

Comment: I think you are not closing modal when you are saving information and reloading state. Close it before reloading state, it may resolve your issue.

Comment: @the_mishra I am using the bootstrap modal inside file profile.html like this (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h). How can I close it before reloading the state ?

Comment: `angular.element('#your-modal-id').modal('hide')`

Comment: @the_mishra it still does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154304/discussion-between-the-mishra-and-thach-huynh).

Answer (score 1):

try following:

```
$state.reload();
```

and if will not work try this:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
});
```

Comment: I tried them all but none of them seems to work. Maybe it's because the modal that I used to add device.